# Script created directory according file timestamp and move into respective directory

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have lots of files named like test_file_201701011512000.dat created every day. I need to move these files date wise or month wise directories, if directory is not created then create accordingly.  Please suggest how to go about it.

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: @codeforester: That doesn't seem to matter, as you've written it all for them; there's really nothing gained when you just do someone else work and they learn nothing in the process. Your answer doesn't explain anything in regards to what the functions even do...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assuming all your files are in the same directory.  The files are moved to dest/year/month directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

dest_dir=_your_destination_directory_
# pattern to grab 4 digits of year and 2 digits of month
file_pattern="_([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})"
for file in test_file_*; do
  [[ ! -f $file ]] && continue  # look at regular files only
  if [[ $file =~ $file_pattern ]]; then
    year="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    month="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    destination_dir="$dest_dir/$year/$month"
    [[ ! -d $destination_dir ]] && mkdir -p "$destination_dir"
    echo "Moving $file to $destination_dir"
    mv "$file" "$destination_dir"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working , but month is showing only in 2 digit i.e.12,11,10 but i want month like 201312,201401,201402, Please suggest where can change

Comment: It is a small change - you have to remove the `/` between $year and $month.